# Memory usage does not add up to total on Windows

Tags: windows-10, memory

Opening new processes on my computer takes longer than it used to. I have a 32 GB Windows 10 machine but the top 5 processes by usage in the task manager, use less than 100 MB each. There is no way I can get the processes to add up to 2 GB, let alone 32.

Commit memory in the resource monitor may add up to a higher number than in the task manager but AFAIK commit memory is not the same as RAM.

I know idle memory is a waste of resources, but the reason I got a 32GB machine is so that when I need to open a new process I want it to open quickly and run smoothly. Is the task manager not giving me a full picture of my memory usage?

Comment: It depends. For example if you use virtualization in some manner the task manager view might not be 100% accurate. If a process takes long to open it might also be the disk that's slow(er).